# When dragging a div using jsPlumb its id is not yet interpolated from AngularJS binding

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb

My flowgraph uses jsPlumb to make the nodes draggable and later on allow for connections between nodes. However, even only with the dragging I am held up by an error.

Whenever I drag a node, the console logs an error message for each pixel moved. The error is `jsPlumb function failed : TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined` and I managed to track it down to be in `jsplumb.js` line 4919.
There, the local variable `elId` (which represents the `id` of the node's `div`) is set correctly to `node-1`. However, inside of the `managedElements` object the node is saved with the key `node-{{$ctrl.node.id}}`. Therefore, when attempting to access `managedElements[elId].el` (in line 4919), the (correct) `elId` is not found as a key, which prompts the error above.

I could not figure out when `managedId` is set. The controller that is part of the node `.component` has the following code (the `JsPlump` service simply returns a `jsPlumbInstance`):

```
const NodeController = ['$element', 'JsPlumb', function ($element, JsPlumb) {
  const nodeDiv = $element.children('.node');
  JsPlumb.draggable(nodeDiv);
}];
```

I also tried setting the `draggable` method when the template is fully linked (I'm new to AngularJS and was not sure whether the interpolation has taken place when the controller is called):

```
const NodeController = ['$element', 'JsPlumb', function ($element, JsPlumb) {
  const ctrl = this;

  ctrl.$postLink = function () {
    const nodeDiv = $element.children('.node');
    JsPlumb.draggable(nodeDiv);
  };
}];
```

All of these snippets still produce an error in the console whenever a mouse move event is fired.

Do you have an idea of how I can resolve this bug? Can I somehow provide the correct `id` for the `managedElements`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `$element` did not interpolate the `id` and therefore an element with an invalid `id` was passed through to jsPlumb and got saved in `managedElements`.

Since I do not know how to access the interpolated element inside the controller, I manually reset the `id` on the element in the controller and then passed the element on to jsPlumb.